# One page checkout in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

Can anyone tell me in brief what is the difference between one page checkout and normal checkout in magento 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of OnePage Checkout is to gather the information that is needed, and complete the sale as quickly as possible. When Onepage Checkout is enabled, the entire checkout process takes place on a single page. Each section of the checkout information is expanded as needed.
Otherwise it will expand more than one page for gathering the information regarding shipment, payment and placing the order.

Comment: I have disabled one page checkout but i am not able to proceed to checkout. I gets stuck at shopping cart page. Can u tell me how normal checkout works then?

Comment: I told you the theoretical difference but when dealing it as a Module and if you disable default Onepage checkout you need any other module installed for checkout purpose.